# SVN diff issue from show log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been using SVN from 7 years. I have strange problem now, recently my system has been formatted. I installed SVN again. From that time i am not able to view the differences from any revision. I am getting the below window. I have added local directory Base file and SVN path in Their file but no use. If someone faced same issue please suggest some way to solve it.

[image]

Comment: What settings do you have at "Diff Viewer"? Having "TortoiseMerge" checked should be the only configuration needed as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

TortoiseMerge isn't diff tool. You have to select another in TSVN's configuration (at least kdiff3 is bundled)

Comment: I have installed kdiff3, I am getting the same kind of window as above from kdiff3 too.

Comment: Er... Yes, it is a diff tool :-? (Not my DV anyway.)

Comment: @Lazy Badger  Alvaro Gonzalez, can you please suggest some other solution